# HostConfig for adaptive cards in bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm using the adaptive cards with the bot framework node.js SDK. Sending those adaptive cards to my users already succeeded. Now I want to go further:

On the [site](http://adaptivecards.io/documentation/#display-hostconfigschema) they tell you can customize the look and feel of the card further. Now I wonder how this works? How can I adjust this hostconfig file to change colors, padding, background etc. And how can I use CSS and HTML to build cards, like they say on the site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the HostConfig you can call to `AdaptiveCards.setHostConfig` and pass your configuration. An example:

```
AdaptiveCards.setHostConfig({
    "supportsInteractivity": true,
    "strongSeparation": {
        "spacing": 10,
        "lineThickness": 1,
        "lineColor": "#EEEEEE"
    },
    "fontFamily": "Segoe UI",
    "fontSizes": {
        "small": 12,
        "normal": 14,
        "medium": 17,
        "large": 21,
        "extraLarge": 26
    },
    "fontWeights": {
        "lighter": 200,
        "normal": 400,
        "bolder": 600
    },
    "colors": {
        "dark": {
            "normal": "#333333",
            "subtle": "#EE333333"
        },
        "light": {
            "normal": "#FFFFFF",
            "subtle": "#88FFFFFF"
        },
        "accent": {
            "normal": "#2E89FC",
            "subtle": "#882E89FC"
        },
        "attention": {
            "normal": "#5D60B3",
            "subtle": "#DD5D60B3"
        },
        "good": {
            "normal": "#00a000",
            "subtle": "#DD00a000"
        },
        "warning": {
            "normal": "#c00000",
            "subtle": "#DDc00000"
        }
    },
    "imageSizes": {
        "small": 40,
        "medium": 80,
        "large": 160
    },
    "actions": {
        "maxActions": 5,
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        },
        "buttonSpacing": 20,
        "stretch": false,
        "showCard": {
            "actionMode": "inlineEdgeToEdge",
            "inlineCardSpacing": 16,
            "backgroundColor": "#08000000",
            "padding": {
                "top": 16,
                "right": 16,
                "bottom": 16,
                "left": 16
            }
        },
        "actionsOrientation": "horizontal",
        "actionAlignment": "left"
    },
    "adaptiveCard": {
        "backgroundColor": "#fafafa",
        "padding": {
            "left": 10,
            "top": 10,
            "right": 10,
            "bottom": 10
        }
    },
    "container": {
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        },
        "normal": {},
        "emphasis": {
            "backgroundColor": "#cccccc",
            "borderColor": "#aaaaaa",
            "borderThickness": {
                "top": 1,
                "right": 1,
                "bottom": 1,
                "left": 1
            },
            "padding": {
                "top": 10,
                "right": 10,
                "bottom": 10,
                "left": 10
            }
        }
    },
    "textBlock": {
        "color": "dark",
        "separations": {
            "small": {
                "spacing": 10
            },
            "normal": {
                "spacing": 10
            },
            "medium": {
                "spacing": 10
            },
            "large": {
                "spacing": 10
            },
            "extraLarge": {
                "spacing": 10
            }
        }
    },
    "image": {
        "size": "medium",
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        }
    },
    "imageSet": {
        "imageSize": "medium",
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        }
    },
    "factSet": {
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        },
        "title": {
            "color": "dark",
            "size": "normal",
            "isSubtle": false,
            "weight": "bolder"
        },
        "value": {
            "color": "dark",
            "size": "normal",
            "isSubtle": false,
            "weight": "normal"
        },
        "spacing": 10
    },
    "input": {
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        }
    },
    "columnSet": {
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        }
    },
    "column": {
        "separation": {
            "spacing": 10
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I'm using Node.js and sending the card like this:
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                    .addAttachment({
                        contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        content: _json with the body_
                    });

So where exactly can I set those configs? It look like you are using the npm package?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the npm package?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you can send an adaptive card by using the npm package?

Comment: Check http://adaptivecards.io/documentation/#create-libraries-typescript and http://adaptivecards.io/documentation/#create-libraries-javascript

Comment: I've noticed there's no "default width" parameter (or something like it) shown in your listing @EzequielJadib Do you know if it's possible to specify a default width for a rendered adaptive card ?

Answer (score 1):

HostConfig is about the application which is receiving the card having control over the look and the feel of the rendering so it matches the host application UX.

The producer of the card can control spacing using "none", "default" or "strong", but it 's up the recipient to decide what that means.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/AdaptiveCards.md

from above you can see

```
      AdaptiveCards.setHostConfig( {YOUR JSON HERE} );
```